# How do I turn on the lamp in blender?

Tags: lighting

I'm very new to blender. I was working on another project and closed the blender application, when I tried to open it again the light source is not working anymore! please help!
[image]

Comment: When you open up blender again, it starts in Solid Preview mode. Press Z in the 3D viewport and select "Rendered" from the pie menu to see your lights. You can also pick "Rendered Preview" from the 4 little side-by-side "circles" at the top-right of the viewport (left to right - wireframe, solid, material preview, rendered - the one you want (rendered) is the furthest circle to the right).